# gnu ld treating assembly output as linker script, how to fix? or am i doing something wrong in my compiling?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

i've been working on my kernel project and to simulate it (that is to run it on QEMU), i need it as a .iso file.

I have an assembly file and to assemble it - `as --32 boot.s -o boot.o`

and for the main code (which is in c++), to compile it - `gcc -S kernel.cpp -lstdc++ -o kernel.o`

gives no error. but,

while linking it with this linker script:-

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* we need 1MB of space atleast */
    . = 1M;

    /* text section */
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

    /* read only data section */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /* data section */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    /* bss section */
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }

}
```

(the linking command i'm using is `ld -T linker.ld kernel.o boot.o -o OS.bin`)

it says:-

```
ld:kernel.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
ld:kernel.o:1: syntax error
```

am i doing something wrong with linking or assembling boot.s or compiling kernel.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -S` produces assembly language, but `ld` expects an object file.  Somewhere in between you have to run the assembler.

There's no particular need to use the assembler output, so most likely you want to use `-c`, which does compilation and then assembly to produce an object file, instead of `-S`:

```
gcc -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o
```

The `-lstdc++` is useless because it only applies when linking, and anyway it seems unlikely that you can successfully use the standard C++ library in a kernel.

Comment: hey @NateEldredge, now i'm getting boot.o as i386 architecture and kernel.o as x86_64. it says it's
 incompatible, what do i do now?

Comment: Ask a new question.

Comment: now it's solved, added "-m32" to gcc command